# Is it possible to handle auth in Laravel from 2 db?

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have an old projects db for which i need to create a new web interface. Main problem with auth is that the login and password is in old db, but I can't write there, so basically i need to get auth data from one db and write the remember token to the other. Is it possible?

I already tried to play with `eloquent`, but stuck on the validation as my password is in base64...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set preffered connection on your model - in this case User model.

**1. Add this connection attribute to the `models/User.php` file**

```
protected $connection = 'olddb';
```

**2. Edit your `config/database.php` file and add connection as specified above**

```
'connections' => array(

    //...

    'olddb' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    //...

),
```

Since Laravel's Auth is tied to user model, Auth will use this connection instead of your default.

Comment: is it possible to disable remember me function?

Comment: of course it is. Call `Auth::attempt($createndials, false)` where `false` means *do not remember me*.